# ERROR:Unable to create preboard manifest idevicerestore.exe

Tags: ios, libimobiledevice

## idevicerestore.exe ios15.3.1.ipsw

return :

```
Checking if device requires stashbag...
ERROR: img4_create_local_manifest: Unhandled component 'Ap,SystemVolumeCanonicalMetadata' - can't create manifest
ERROR: Unable to create preboard manifest.
```

I downloaded the last updated binary from [imobiledevice-net](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net) and I am on Windows 10.

Also I checked idevicerestore.exe [code](https://cgit.sukimashita.com/idevicerestore.git/tree/src/idevicerestore.c) and I found this:

```
if (needs_preboard) {
                info("Checking if device requires stashbag...\n");
                plist_t manifest;
                if (get_preboard_manifest(client, build_identity, &manifest) < 0) {
                    error("ERROR: Unable to create preboard manifest.\n");
                    return -1;
                }
```

Then I checked

> get_preboard_manifest

function and I understand that the problem is because of

> img4_create_local_manifest

Can any one help me fix this issue or to find some way to solve this programitically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download last binary from github action-> artifacts:
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/idevicerestore/actions

you also may need dependencies:

1. [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist/actions)
2. [libimobiledevice-glue](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice-glue/actions)
3. [libusbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd/actions)
4. [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/actions)
5. [libirecovery](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libirecovery/actions)